# Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix in $\mathbb{C}$. Find $B^n$ where $n$ is an integer

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I believe there is a solution to this, just from some small examples, it seems that there is always a solution matrix $B$ such that $B^n = A$.
Is there a way to show that for every integer $n$, then there exists a $B$ such that
$B^n = A = PDP^{-1}$ for diagonalizable $A$, $P$ is matrix with eigenvectors of $A$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries with eigenvalues.

It looks to me that I can just solve to find $P$, so then
$B = PD^{\frac{1}{n}}P^{-1}.$
Is this true, or are there conditions required on $A$ (such as $A$ being a unitary matrix)?

Comment: As long as $A$ is diagonalizable, your expression for $B$ works.

Comment: Thanks. Is this true for all $n$ in$ \mathbb{R}$?